# Mongoimport duplicate keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

When I use mongoimport to import a json file into my collection only the first object of the same name gets imported.

Original abc.json

```
{
   "timestamp":"100",
   "layers":{
      "a":{
         "aa":"0",
         "ab":"1",
         "ac":"2"
      },
      "b":
         {
          "ba":"0",
          "bb":"1",
          "bc":"2"
         },
       "b":
         {
            "missing": "1",
            "missing2": "2"
         }

   }
}
```

Import command looks like this:

```
mongoimport --db myDB --collection myCollection --file abc.json
```

Output of db.myCollection.find().limit(1) looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("5ac723b5d1b034017a6f187f"),
   "timestamp":"100",
   "layers":{
      "a":{
         "aa":"0",
         "ab":"1",
         "ac":"2"
      },
      "b":{
         "ba":"0",
         "bb":"1",
         "bc":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to merge this duplicate key with mongoimport?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo import will import exactly same document as it is in your valid json file.

*sample json file abc.json*

```
{
    "timestamp": "100",
    "layers": {
        "a": {
            "aa": "0",
            "ab": "1",
            "ac": "2"
        },
        "b": {
            "ba": "0",
            "bb": "1",
            "bc": "2"
        }
    }
}
{
    "timestamp": "100",
    "layers": {
        "a": {
            "aa": "0",
            "ab": "1",
            "ac": "2"
        },
        "b": [{
                "ba": "0",
                "bb": "1",
                "bc": "2",
                "baa": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ],
                "bba": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "missing": "1",
                "missing2": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

mongodb import command from console

```
mongoimport --db myDB --collection myCollection --file abc.json
```

*import logs*

```
2018-04-05T23:55:16.500+0530    connected to: localhost
2018-04-05T23:55:17.727+0530    imported 2 documents
```

find

```
> db.myCollection.find().pretty()
```

console view

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac6678b597b04c8add377d9"),
        "timestamp" : "100",
        "layers" : {
                "a" : {
                        "aa" : "0",
                        "ab" : "1",
                        "ac" : "2"
                },
                "b" : {
                        "ba" : "0",
                        "bb" : "1",
                        "bc" : "2"
                }
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac6678b597b04c8add377da"),
        "timestamp" : "100",
        "layers" : {
                "a" : {
                        "aa" : "0",
                        "ab" : "1",
                        "ac" : "2"
                },
                "b" : [
                        {
                                "ba" : "0",
                                "bb" : "1",
                                "bc" : "2",
                                "baa" : [
                                        "1",
                                        "2",
                                        "3"
                                ],
                                "bba" : [
                                        "1",
                                        "2",
                                        "3"
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "missing" : "1",
                                "missing2" : "2"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I changed the question. I use tshark to generate these jsons. I have tshark 2.5.1 on my client device and 2.4.2 on my server. 2.5.1 obviously generates the files correctly, but 2.4.2 doesn't.  Since I created this sample on my client device I got it wrong. Sry.